# Using R online - without installing it

Tags: r

Is there a possibility to use R in a webinterface without the need to install it?

I have only one small script which I like to run but I just want to give it a shot without a long installation procedure.

Thank you.

Comment: A "long installation procedure"?  Only if you build from source.  There are binaries for most popular OS distributions and it takes < 5 minutes to download and install them.

Comment: @Joshua: You are right - but "long" is relative, esp. when you compare it to just copy&paste into a webinterface.

Comment: @vonjd: But you could have downloaded, installed, and run your script in less time than it took to write your question and wait for an answer. ;-)

Comment: @Joshua Good point.  But in some work environments it can take a lot of effort just to get the permission to install *any* executable on a machine.  And on Windows systems, most installations, even after a subsequent uninstall, litter the machine with detritus that accumulates over time and helps bog everything down, so if you aren't *sure* you're going to use some software there's incentive not to install it.

Comment: @whuber: I was somewhat joking with my last comment.  I'm personally familiar with some of those constraints and I realize the benefits to a sandbox.

Comment: You can put an entire Windows installation of R (and RStudio for ease of use) on a flash drive. Just copy the R folder. Then you can take it with you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about statistics.

Comment: This site has a simple R context: http://www.r-fiddle.org/

Comment: Here's R in a jupyter notebook in your browser : https://rnotebook.io & https://tmpnb.org/

Comment: @Ben: Thank you - what a pity that this thread was closed!

Comment: Off topic and all that, but:  ``rextester.com`` and ``repl.it`` work well. If you create an account, you'll probably like ``datacamp.com`` even better.

Comment: How can a question with so much interest - let's not forget that a number of people are working under the tyranny of IT department little men - can be possibly be closed? In any event, I just found [trinket](https://trinket.io/), which allows running R and Python on your browser. Fantastic!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there are some Rweb interface, like [this one](http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/Rweb/) (dead as of September 2020), RDDR [online REPL](https://rdrr.io/snippets/), or [Repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/).

**Note:** Installation of the R software is pretty straightforward and quick, on any platform.

Comment: No longer works

Comment: Thanks @canderson156! Added a few more options.

Comment: @chl Nice to see you again!

Comment: Thanks @whuber!

Answer (score 8):

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) also has R included with a Python interface. The Sage system is available. Since a couple of years, the prefered way to run SageMath is via [CoCalc](https://www.cocalc.com/). It also allows you to run R directly, e.g. in a [Jupyter notebook using the R kernel](https://share.cocalc.com/share/20e4a191-73ea-4921-80e9-0a5d792fc511/test/faithful.ipynb?viewer=share).

Example:

```
r.data("faithful")
r.lm("eruptions ~ waiting", data=r.faithful)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = sage2, data = sage0)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      waiting  
   -1.87402      0.07563
```

Comment: I tried to run an r script in a Sage webinterface but it didn't work - it said that there was an error creating a png (no X.11 available or sth.)

Comment: This python interface is freakin hilarious. Do you have any clue how it built? I mean I could make use of a much much simpler system but need to host on my own.

Answer (score 8):

Also, if you want to provide a solution to other users, you can set up a webserver with [RApache](http://rapache.net/).

Comment: And now there's [Rack](http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/4723187316/introducing-rack).

Comment: @chl And now, it is called [Rook](http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/4723187316/introducing-rook) (-;

Answer (score 6):

Some of the pastebin services will allow you to enter R code. For example, [ideone](http://ideone.com). Here is a [very silly hello world](http://ideone.com/bAwPM) in R. I believe ideone limits you to 15 seconds compute time per run, and no fancy IDE, despite the name.

Comment: The example is empty now. I was curious to see it :(

Comment: It seems the links did not survive an API change; a new hellow world is here: http://ideone.com/6xpOl4

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) This has a desktop and web version. I have used the desktop version and it is pretty cool.

Comment: The link to download the R web interface installer can be found at: http://rstudio.org/download/